# load glb model in SCNScene swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a .glb file in document folder, how do I get the image and load into scnScene? like how I load a uiimage from document folder

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory,     nsUserDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath          = paths.first
{
   let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("Image2.png")
   let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path
```

is it possible to load .glb in SCNScene?

```
   let scene = SCNScene(named: "latest.glb")
```

Answer (score 1):

answering my own question, I used GLTFSceneKit

```
 let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                 in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                                       .appendingPathComponent("test.glb")
    
    var scene: SCNScene
            do {
                let sceneSource = try GLTFSceneSource(url: path)
                scene = try sceneSource.scene()
            } catch {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load with this library also GLTFKit2

```
GLTFAsset.load(with: url, options: [:]) { (progress, status, maybeAsset, maybeError, _) in
    // Check for completion and/or error, use asset if complete, etc.
}
```